# Board and library updates required caused an error

Tags: avrdude, programmer

I compiled my code several times today,
I would quit and restart randomly through the day.
each time I started I get a error box board and libraries need updates.
I did an AVR board up date, then compiled and now I get this every time.....

---

avrdude: no programmer has been specified on the command line or the config file
         Specify a programmer using the -c option and try again

---

Yes I have tried rebooting my Windows 7 64 bit AMD machine.

this is on IDE "Arduino 1.6.8"

Of course I made the mistake of not backing up my IDE folders in the belief that an update would not screw my IDE up.

Nothing will upload, not even any of the examples.
I turned on Show Verbose output during Compilation, and upload
I pasted the full output and it was 4500 char to many for this so I turned of the compilation check and left just the upload check on show verbose errors

I loaded in the example blink,

### the file followed by the IDE lower window text.

```c
/*
  Blink
  Turns on an LED on for one second, then off for one second, repeatedly.

  Most Arduinos have an on-board LED you can control. On the Uno and
  Leonardo, it is attached to digital pin 13. If you're unsure what
  pin the on-board LED is connected to on your Arduino model, check
  the documentation at http://www.arduino.cc

  This example code is in the public domain.

  modified 8 May 2014
  by Scott Fitzgerald
 */


// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);              // wait for a second
}
```

---

END OF FILE 
Copy and paste of the lower IDE window  last lines the same as above

---

```c
Sketch uses 928 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
C:\Users\Lee\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino2/bin/avrdude -CC:\Users\Lee\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino2/etc/avrdude.conf -v true -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM10 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\Lee\AppData\Local\Temp\build9c9ef3bdfe2fccb480bc6e4bac749e41.tmp/Blink.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jun 22 2016 at 16:05:21
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\Lee\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino2/etc/avrdude.conf"


avrdude: no programmer has been specified on the command line or the config file
         Specify a programmer using the -c option and try again
```

---

There is that line again   What do I do to fix this?
besides deleting everything and starting all over again?

I do not want to delete and start over

Comment: try to check your setting in `Tools->Board` and `Tools->Programmer`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading Error: no programmer has been specified](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30034/uploading-error-no-programmer-has-been-specified)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very much like the problem I had when I updated my ARV version,I was also getting "no programmer has been specified error", I run Windows 7 32bit, the way i got out of it was to go back to the update screen when it pops up and in Arduino ARV Boards area....select versions....I went back to version 1.6.10...now it all works again.....at this point I am no longer updating my ARV, but I will after a few more version updates come out, there is obviously something that conflicts at this stage, if you google the problem you will find other of ways to fix this.