# Uploading Error: no programmer has been specified

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, arduino-ide, uploading

Whenever I upload a code I get this error:

`avrdude: no programmer has been specified on the command line or the config file
         Specify a programmer using the -c option and try again`

I am able to upload from other PCs, but ever since I got the newest IDE, it stopped working. I even tried downgrading to 1.6.8, and still i get this error... Any help? Thanks,

Sean

Comment: Check what programmer you have selected in the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

This issue occurs when using Arduino IDE 1.6.8 or older with Arduino AVR Boards 1.6.12 or 1.6.14. There are two solutions:

1. Upgrade your Arduino IDE to 1.6.9 or newer by downloading and
   installing the appropriate file from
   https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software.
2. Downgrade your Arduino AVR Boards version to 1.6.11 or older(or 1.6.13) via
   **Tools > Board > Boards Manager...**

I submitted a pull request to fix this backwards compatibility issue and it was merged by the Arduino developers so this issue will no longer occur with Arduino AVR Boards 1.6.15 and up. It explains the cause of the issue:
https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/5427